# laravel избежать дублирования при join

Tags: php, sql, laravel, join

Как избежать дублирования данных при `join` в `laravel`?

*Пример:*
2 таблицы: в одной пользователи, в другой картинки.
У каждого пользователя может быть несколько картинок в таблице картинок.

Как в запросе избежать дублирования при `join` (в запросе выводит все картинки для пользователя дублирую пользователя) и вывести для каждого пользователя одну картинку?

***Код:***

```
$data = DB::table('users')
  ->leftJoin('users_image', function($join) {
    $join->on('users_image.name', '=', 'users.name');
  })
  ->select('*')
  ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Если у пользователя может быть больше одной картинки, то которую одну нужно вывести?

Comment: Да. В запросе нужно получать одно изображение

Comment: Которое из нескольких?

Comment: Первое (по мин id) например

Comment: Не делать всё одним запросом. Пользоваться отдельно объектом пользователя, и списком картинок. А не объектом картинко-пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам необходимо выбрать уникальные строки, то есть выборка только не повторяющихся сочетаний "пользователь => картинка", то можно добавить условие distinct():

```
$data = DB::table('users')
  ->leftJoin('users_image', function($join) {
    $join->on('users_image.name', '=', 'users.name');
  })
  ->distinct()
  ->paginate(5);
```

В Вашем случае, `select('*')` не нужно, потому что по умолчанию выбираются все записи. Для корректного срабатывания условия `ditinct()` необходимо указать конкретные поля для выборки, например `->select('users.name','users_image.name')` , в таком случае выберутся нужные поля и на них наложится `distinct()`, то есть возьмутся уникальные значения.

Если же Вам нужно выбрать только одну картинку для каждого пользователя, то необходимо добавить дополнительное условие в запросе:

```
        $data = DB::table('users')
              ->leftJoin('users_image', function($join) {
                $join->on('users_image.name', '=', 'users.name');
              })
              ->distinct()
              ->whereIn('users_image.id', DB::raw('select max(id) from users_image group by name'))
->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, object given, called in

Comment: Да, простите, запрос вернул коллекцию, а должен быть массив. Надо добавить `pluck()` . Вот так: `->whereIn('users_image.id', DB::raw('select max(id) from users_image group by name')->pluck('id'))`

Comment: Ошибка Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression::pluck() in file

Comment: Вот последний код запроса: $data = DB::table('data')
                    ->leftJoin('image', function($join) {
                        $join->on('image.Lot', '=', 'data.lotNumber');
                    })
                    // ->select('copart_image.href', 'copart_data.lotNumber')
                    ->distinct()
                    ->whereIn('image.ID', DB::raw('select max(ID) from image group by image.Lot')->pluck('ID'))
                    ->paginate($size);
                }

Comment: `$data = DB::table('data') ->leftJoin('image', function($join) { $join->on('image.Lot', '=', 'data.lotNumber'); }) // ->select('copart_image.href', 'copart_data.lotNumber') ->distinct() ->whereIn('image.ID', DB::raw('select max(ID) from image group by image.Lot')->get()->pluck('ID')) ->paginate($size); }` Вот так попробуйте. Ключевое слово ->get() упустили

Comment: Снова ошибка - Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression::get()

Answer (score 0):

Исправил запрос на ->whereIn('image.ID', [DB::raw('select max(ID) from image group by image.Lot')]) и все вывелось как надо